# MSSQL: Why won't ROW_NUMBER give me expected results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, row-number

I have a table with a datetime field ("time") and an int field ("index")

Please see the query and the picture below. I want ROW_NUMBER to count from 1 when the index changes, also if the index value exists in previous rows. The red text indicates the output that I want to get from the query. How can I modify the query to give me the expected results?

[image]

The query:

```
select rv.[time], rv.[index], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rv.[index] ORDER BY  rv.[time],  rv.[index] ASC) AS Row# 
from 
tbl
```

Comment: Why is this happening? Because you partition by Index and nothing else. Therefore, the tuple <4, 10> is merely the 10 row with Index = 4. There is no reason to expect the numbering to restart at 1 for this or any "following" row. I'll guess that you think rows have a particular order and you can rely on that in writing code. They don't - learn that concept well.

Answer (score 5):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You need to identify groups of adjacent rows.  In this case, I think the simplest method is the difference of row numbers:

```
select rv.*,
       row_number() over (partition by index, (seqnum - seqnum_2) order by time) as row_num
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by index order by time) as seqnum_2
      from tbl t
     ) rv;
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  If you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference between the two row number values identifies adjacent values that are the same.

Also, you should not use names like `time` and `index` for columns, because these a keywords in SQL.  I have not escaped the names in the above query.  I encourage you to give your columns and tables names that do not need to be escaped.